# How to select rows from numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array nList and a list of tags tList which preserves the order of nList, and records the class each element from nList belongs to. For example, for two different classes 0 and 1

```
nList = [11 22 33 44 55]
tList = [0 0 1 0 1]
```

meaning that 11, 22, 44 belong together, and so do 33, 55.

Is there a pythonic way to select elements from nList by class?

I have tried

```
for clusterId in np.unique(cls):
indices = [i for i in range(len(cls)) if cls[i]==clusterId]
print 'Class ', clusterId
for idx in indices:
    print '\t', x[idx,].tolist()
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
#selecting class 0
>>> nList[tList == 0]
array([11, 22, 44])

#selecting class 1
>>> nList[tList == 1]
array([33, 55])
```